# How to check if any PDF is password protected in Android without using 3rd party solutions

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdfrenderer

I am trying to import a pdf in my application using PdfRenderer - Android's in-built solution.

With this i am facing problem mentioned on this link.

[google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178566)

My requirement is to check if any password is password protected or not **without** using any 3rd party libs or jar.

How can this be done ?

Note : Similar reported issues discuss solution using 3rd party libs only but this is not i want.

I am already able to accomplish most of my job using PdfRenderer class.
And just to check if any pdf is password protected, i do not want to use any library.

Comment: ***without** using any 3rd party libs* means that you will have to re-invent parts of them. If your input documents are arbItrary, that is not trivial.

Comment: Where or how should i start ? If it asks for a lot i will reconsider using 3rd party libs.

Comment: *Where or how should i start* - read the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), especially the sections 7.5 "File Structure" and 7.6 "Encryption". Then write code to read the file trailer dictionary (which *may* be absorbed by a cross reference stream dictionary) and inspect its **Encrypt** entry.

Answer (score 0):

In Android SDK there is android.graphics.pdf package to work with pdf document but there is no suitable method to check pdf password is vaild or not.

So I am recommend to use [PdfBox-Android](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) library to check pdf password is vaild or not without opening pdf document.

Here is the example code for that.

```
public boolean isPdfPasswordValid(String filePath, String password) {
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file,password);
         if (document.isEncrypted()) {
             document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
             document.getPage(0);
             document.close();
             return true;
         } else {
             document.close();
             return false;
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

> Add this gradle dependancy in module level build.gradle file in android project

```
implementation 'com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:2.0.27.0'
```